# Can't connect to Ubuntu server from a specific client

Tags: remote, ping

I'm having problems pinging my local Ubuntu server (20.04.3 LTS) using my Windows machine. Sometimes it works, but most of the times it returns: `Reply from <client ip>: Destination host unreachable.` I don't have any problems pinging and SSH'ing from another Linux machine (tested with *Raspberry Pi* and Android phone).

The logs (`/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/kern.log`, etc...) don't update while I'm trying to connect. The *iptables* don't block that client's IP and I haven't modified them.

How can I continue debugging this problem?

Comment: This is not a problem with your server, but with your windows client apparently

Comment: You need to consider, are the two devices on the same IP network with the same subnet mask? Is either/both using WiFi or are both wired? Have you run up Wireshark on both devices (a) to check the ping packets are leaving the client, (b) that the packets are arriving at the server, (c) that ping replies are leaving the server, and (d) if those reply packets are being seen by the client

Comment: It turned out to be an ARP problem, Thanks for the suggestion to use Wireshark, it will be useful to diagnose the ARP problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions: Switch off the energy savings on your ethernet card. Check your arp table. You can add statically the linux ip into arp table

```
arp -s <server.ip> <server mac address>
```

In older cards, check the autonegotiating.

Comment: The server wasn't in the client's ARP table. Pinging the client from the server added a dynamic entry inside the client's ARP table, which solved the problem. I don't know why this isn't happening automatically, but this answers my question, thanks.

Comment: If you use the arp -s, your windows don't forget the server's ip. (Careful, if the server mac address changed then a new problem occurred :)....)